# Mono and Nginx: Index (/) 404 served by StaticFileHadler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nginx, mono

I've successfully set up **Mono (Stable 4.2.3.4)** on Ubuntu 14.04 with **NGINX (1.8.1)** to host **ASP.NET MVC** apps and it works great. The only thing I am not able to solve is the "index/root (/) 404" problem.

I am using custom CustomMvcRouteHandler for catchall route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UrlHandler", // Route name
    "{*url}",
    null,
    null,
    new[] { "web.Controllers" }
    ).RouteHandler = new CustomMvcRouteHandler();
```

This works great and all expected requests are routed through the CustomMvcRouterHandler(); **but not for index (/)**. For any reason the index request (/) is being served by StaticFileHandler and throws this error:

**System.Web.HttpException**:The resource cannot be found.

**Description:** HTTP 404.The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

**Details:** Requested URL: /

Exception stack trace:

```
    at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) <0x407e59f0 + 0x00753> in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) <0x407e5720 + 0x00153> in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () <0x408c5000 + 0x04485> in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () <0x408c2730 + 0x00057> in <filename unknown>:0
```

**Please note that it works this way only on Mono, on my Windows dev machine and even on any Windows IIS hosting the same web app with the same web.config etc. works OK even for root (/) requests and those requests are being routed through CustomMvcRouteHandler().**

What I really don't understand is why Mono serves index (/) using StaticFileHandler. If I create index.html file in root of the web structure then it is served by StaticFileHandler (as expected, because static file handler is looking for that file).

This is the NGINX config file for the site:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    access_log /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    location / {
        fastcgi_index /;
        root /var/www/example.com/www/;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

The workaround I am using now is chaning the line:

```
        fastcgi_index /;
```

to

```
        fastcgi_index /Default.aspx;
```

This way the root access (/) is being changed to /Default.aspx and routed through the ASP.NET MVC pipeline, but of course I need to change the code and treat the /Default.aspx as /.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution hour later after posting the question, damn.

The problem was with catchall route specification and having the "defaults" parameter NULL. Changing it this way solved the problem:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     "UrlHandler", // Route name
      url: "{*url}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
      constraints: null,
      namespaces: new[] { "web.Controllers" }
      ).RouteHandler = new CustomMvcRouteHandler();
```

See the defaults for controller = "Home", action = "Index". Having the defaults specified even the index (/) route is being served by ASP.NET MVC pipeline.

The side effect of this is, that RouteData.Values for "controller" and "action" are added to the collection as specified in defaults and so if you want to add them in code (as me), exception will be thrown:

**An item with the same key has already been added.**

So it's better to check for and remove those values if neccessary.

```
 if (requestContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("controller"))
     requestContext.RouteData.Values.Remove("controller");
 if (requestContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("action"))
     requestContext.RouteData.Values.Remove("action");
```

*P.S.: It's all about those small differences when hosting on IIS vs. Mono :).*